# npm will not ignore my TypeScript source code file no matter what I try

Tags: typescript, npm, glob, npm-publish

I have an open source project that is written in TypeScript, and is compiled to JavaScript and then published as a CLI tool via `npm publish`.

I've been *unable* to *exclude* the TypeScript source code from the npm package, and there are other `*.ts` files that seem to get included at random (but we'll focus on one file here).

I do not have a *problem* including the TypeScript source files, but that's just adding extra bytes to the package for something the user will never need.

I can reproduce the problem with a very small setup

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "example",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "readme.js"
}
```

I've tried a very aggressive ignore list:

**.npmignore**

```
**/*
*.ts
**
*
*.*
readme.ts
```

Create some source code files

```sh
touch readme.ts
touch readme.js
```

Now if I try to generate a npm package it will include the `readme.ts` file.

```sh
$ npm pack
npm notice
npm notice package: example@1.0.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice 0   readme.js
npm notice 76B package.json
npm notice 0   readme.ts
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
npm notice name:          example
npm notice version:       1.0.0
npm notice filename:      example-1.0.0.tgz
npm notice package size:  195 B
npm notice unpacked size: 76 B
npm notice shasum:        a1ee7cc6b7b0d1e2eccf870e95d7df38c5dcb609
npm notice integrity:     sha512-ppNEfKEvT9DEP[...]+d16IWbrj7OdA==
npm notice total files:   3
npm notice
example-1.0.0.tgz
```

So why is it including `readme.ts`?

I have all files excluded, and only the `readme.js` is referenced in the `package.json` file.

```sh
$ npm --version
6.13.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Files named `readme.*` (e.g. `readme.foo`, `readme.quux`, etc) will be included by npm regardless of how you try to negate it in your [.npmignore](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) file.

---

#### NPM's test file:

In one of npm's tests for [npm-cli](https://github.com/npm/cli) titled *"certain files included unconditionally"* starting at line [`#511`](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/c1522be2406a0ea4f14c85753edd42ddd8d7e180/test/tap/pack-files-and-ignores.js#L511) they include a test for a file named *[`readme.randomext`](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/c1522be2406a0ea4f14c85753edd42ddd8d7e180/test/tap/pack-files-and-ignores.js#L523)*.

From observing this test we can conclude that any file named `readme.*` is going to be included in the tarball (`.tgz`) file, even though it may be specified in the `.npmignore` file.

Below is an excerpt from the aforementioned NPM test file named [`pack-files-and-ignores.js`](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/c1522be2406a0ea4f14c85753edd42ddd8d7e180/test/tap/pack-files-and-ignores.js)

> ```js
> test('certain files included unconditionally', function (t) {
>   var fixture = new Tacks(
>     Dir({
>       'package.json': File({
>         name: 'npm-test-files',
>         version: '1.2.5'
>       }),
>       '.npmignore': File(
>         'package.json',
>         'README',
>         'Readme',
>         'readme.md',
>         'readme.randomext',   // <----
>         'changelog',
>         'CHAngelog',
>         'ChangeLOG.txt',
>         'history',
>         'HistorY',
>         'HistorY.md',
>         'license',
>         'licence',
>         'LICENSE',
>         'LICENCE'
>       ),
>       'README': File(''),
>       'Readme': File(''),
>       'readme.md': File(''),
>       'readme.randomext': File(''),     // <----
>       'changelog': File(''),
>       'CHAngelog': File(''),
>       'ChangeLOG.txt': File(''),
>       'history': File(''),
>       'HistorY': File(''),
>       'HistorY.md': File(''),
>       'license': File(''),
>       'licence': File(''),
>       'LICENSE': File(''),
>       'LICENCE': File('')
>     })
>   )
>   withFixture(t, fixture, function (done) {
>     t.ok(fileExists('package.json'), 'package.json included')
>     t.ok(fileExists('README'), 'README included')
>     t.ok(fileExists('Readme'), 'Readme included')
>     t.ok(fileExists('readme.md'), 'readme.md included')
>     t.ok(fileExists('readme.randomext'), 'readme.randomext included')    // <----
>     t.ok(fileExists('changelog'), 'changelog included')
>     t.ok(fileExists('CHAngelog'), 'CHAngelog included')
>     t.ok(fileExists('ChangeLOG.txt'), 'ChangeLOG.txt included')
>     t.ok(fileExists('license'), 'license included')
>     t.ok(fileExists('licence'), 'licence included')
>     t.ok(fileExists('LICENSE'), 'LICENSE included')
>     t.ok(fileExists('LICENCE'), 'LICENCE included')
>     done()
>   })
> })
> ```

---

#### Workarounds:

There are a couple if workarounds you could consider, such as:

1. The simplest is to rename the file to e.g. `read-me.ts` and then specify `read-me.ts` in your `.npmignore` file. However, as you have `*.ts` currently specified in your `.npmignore` it's not actually necessary for you to additionally specify `read-me.ts` too.
2. Or, if that's not possible consider:

   - Add a [`postpack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) script to the scripts section of *package.json*. For instance:

     ```json
     "scripts": {
       "postpack": "node ./fix-it.js",
       ...
     },
     ```
   - Then in `fix-it.js` utilize the [node-tar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar) package to:

     1. Unpack the tarball (`.tgz`).
     2. Remove the unwanted file(s), i.e. `readme.ts`.
     3. Repack to create a new tarball (`.tgz`).
   - Steps to publishing your package then become:

     1. Run `npm pack`

        The `postpack` script will subsequently auto generate the new `.tgz` file without the unwanted file(s).
     2. Run `npm publish ./path/to/mypackage.tgz`

---